# Align a text content with a div

Tags: html, css

I want to align a text with a div. I put the text with `::before` but it is under the div that I made. I tried to add the content directly in the div but it doesn't work. I also tried with a `float` or a `display: inline-block` but it still doesn't want to align.

If somebody have an idea ?

https://jsfiddle.net/mevc37r7/

Comment: image of where you want to align it would help ;)

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mevc37r7/1/

Comment: @JulianEspinosa Yeah ! That's it !! Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

put a div around what you want to align...Example:

```
<div id = "centerText"><h1>This is my text</h1></div>

<style>
#centerText{
    text-align:center;
    //other alignment
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` is only `3px` tall, which is not enough, the text is overflowing. Make it at least `15px`

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/mevc37r7/2/

```
.line{
    margin-top : 70px;
    height:15px;
    width : 500px;
    background-color: #000;
    clear: right;
    float:right;
}

.line::before{
  color:#fff;
  content: "foo";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want the div to be a line, just to a style effect ;)

Comment: Then you may need to change the position value. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mevc37r7/3/